# Add an additional tool-tip/label with a parameter prompt in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, ssrs-2014

We are in a process of migrating all our SAP Webi report to SSRS and is doing a feasibility study on replicating some feature in SAP Webi to SSRS.

In SAP Webi, we have an option to provide an additional label with the prompt value as below,

[image]

When the user searches for Company Name, all the matching `Name` will get displayed along with a additional column `Company Description` which helps user identify whether the selected company is a parent or not. Below is the table structure for your reference

```
Name                 ID  Parent_ID  Company Description
Company A            1   NULL       Parent
Company A Subsidary  2   1         
Company B            3   NULL       Parent
Company SoMe         4   3
```

I tried implementing the same feature in SSRS, but couldn't display multiple label in the prompt drop-down (refer image below).

[image]

Is there anyway I can have an additional label with the prompt ?

Answer (score 1):

Parameters have two relevant properties: `Value` and `Label`.

`Value` is used in your query to select the appropriate data.

`Label` is what is shown in the dropdown for parameter selection.

So you can put whatever you like in the `Label` property to assist the user to make the right selection.

For example, your query for showing the user the available selections might look like this:

```
SELECT Name, Name + " - " + CompanyDescription AS Label
FROM Companies
```

Then for the available values query in your parameter properties, you would set the dataset to this one and map Value to Name and Label to Label.

Comment: Yes I had thought about concatenating Company Desc into Name, but I'd like to check if there's any possibility of having multiple labels

Comment: No, parameter selection is via a drop-down combobox - there is only one label

Comment: alright cool, one more qn - can there be searchable drop-down list as parameter i.e, a box wherein I can type 'Company' and the drop-down list changes accordingly

Comment: Not really, the parameter selection area is quite basic and not customisable, so you can't do any Ajax-like queries.